# How to get the difference between two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

How to get the difference between two DataFrames. For example, I have 2 DataFrames

```
previous_asks =  pd.DataFrame({'price':[1,2,3], 'amount':[10,20,30]})
current_asks = pd.DataFrame({'price':[1,2,3,4], 'amount':[11,20,30,40]})
```

I would like to receive

```
price':[1, 4], 'amount':[11,40]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using pandas:**

```
a1 = list(range(10))
a2 = list(range(5, 8))

b1 = list('abcdefghij')
b2 = list('efy')

df1 =  pd.DataFrame({'price':a1, 'amount':b1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'price':a2, 'amount':b2})

dict_results = dict()
for col in df1:
    dict_results[col] = df1.loc[~ df1[col].isin(df2[col].values), col].values
    print('--', col, dict_results[col])
```

Gives:

```
-- amount ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j']
-- price [0 1 2 3 4 8 9]
```

**Using python3:**

```
set1 = set(a1)
set2 = set(a2)
print(set1 - set2)
```

Gives:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9}
```

I would rather go with python3 here since I think it is much simpler/readable.
If you orignally have pandas dataframes I would convert those to `set` data
type, manipulate those and revert back to `pd.Dataframe` if necessary.

Also it is worth checking out the
[`unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html)
method of a `pd.Series`.